# Why do I keep seeing the same message in my ULS logs?

Tags: 2010, front-end

The following messages continuously repeat in my ULS logs for one of the farm front end web servers.  During this time, the site experienced incomplete page renderings or 404s.  I removed this WFE from the network load balancer and the website started to perform normally.  Any ideas what is going on?  Should I just restart the server?

I'm using Sharepoint 2010, windows server 2008 r2, sql server 2008 r2.

```
08/26/2011 15:32:18.86  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x06E4)   0x075C  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nasq    Medium  Entering monitored scope (Timer Job job-application-server) 3e57f26f-d3d6-41d1-8919-f7ddb809ede3
08/26/2011 15:32:18.86  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x06E4)   0x075C  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job job-application-server). Execution Time=1.60076727608457 3e57f26f-d3d6-41d1-8919-f7ddb809ede3
08/26/2011 15:32:40.91  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x06E4)   0x106C  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nasq    Medium  Entering monitored scope (Timer Job job-application-server-admin-service)   0fd699a2-2e90-44c5-a4ee-0c428c4ee606
08/26/2011 15:32:40.91  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x06E4)   0x106C  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job job-application-server-admin-service). Execution Time=1.57900844583928   0fd699a2-2e90-44c5-a4ee-0c428c4ee606
08/26/2011 15:32:58.93  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x06E4)   0x3244  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nasq    Medium  Entering monitored scope (Timer Job job-timer-locks)    2b5a666d-edf8-4421-be52-dead2a2cbfbc
08/26/2011 15:32:58.93  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x06E4)   0x3244  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job job-timer-locks). Execution Time=9.72150403860955    2b5a666d-edf8-4421-be52-dead2a2cbfbc
```

Comment: Can you post more details about the farm's topology and how it is being used?

Answer (score 4):

Those messages are normal and not related to errors.  SharePoint is just logging how long the various jobs took to execute in case you want to run diagnostics on it.  Here is a more complete explanation: [What does "Leaving Monitored Scope" mean in the log file?](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/sharepoint2010setup/thread/78dbcc16-6ba1-4633-b5d4-e9ed59f481a1)

Comment: I have seen these messages on my other front end web servers.  But in the case of WFE3, these  messages are literally the only messages in the logs.  And they are repeated again and again.

Answer (score 1):

Your server is causing problems but your logs that you posted are not helpful. There is most likely a sync job running that is failing, could be caused by numerous issue.